# Store Date in an array or List in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to get a date from the user in dd/mm/yyyy format and want to store the day, month and year in a list. Is there someway in which this can be achieved?

Thanks,
Chandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access year,month and day using python datetime object

```
import datetime
d = "1/5/2020"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%d/%m/%Y")
result = [date.year,date.month,date.day]
```

output

```
[2020, 5, 1]
```